# GCP AI Platform Notebook driver too old?

Tags: pytorch, nvidia, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am trying to run the following [Hugging Face Transformers tutorial](https://github.com/abhimishra91/transformers-tutorials/blob/master/transformers_multiclass_classification.ipynb) on GCP's AI Platform Notebook with 32 vCPUs, 208 GB RAM, and 2 NVIDIA Tesla T4s.

However, when I try to run the part

`model = DistillBERTClass()`

`model.to(device)`

I get the following Assertion Error:

```
AssertionError: The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old (found version 10010).
Please update your GPU driver by downloading and installing a new
version from the URL: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
Alternatively, go to: https://pytorch.org to install
a PyTorch version that has been compiled with your version
of the CUDA driver.
```

However, when I run
!nvidia-smi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.87.01    Driver Version: 418.87.01    CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   38C    P0    22W /  70W |     10MiB / 15079MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:00:05.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P8    10W /  70W |     10MiB / 15079MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
```

The version on the NVIDIA driver is compatible with the latest PyTorch version, which I am using.
Has anyone else ran into this error, and is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a newer NVIDIA driver version,  we support latest CUDA 11 driver version, and then install Pytorch on top of it:

```
gcloud beta notebooks instances create cuda11 \
--vm-image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
--vm-image-family=common-cu110-notebooks-debian-9 \
--machine-type=n1-standard-1 \
--location=us-west1-a \
--format=json
```

Image family:

- common-cu110-notebooks-debian-9
- common-cu110-notebooks-debian-10

Comment: This did it -- thanks very much! It was the image family that I had to change. Much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that it doesn't work. When I follow your instructions to install a new instance, it doesn't properly integrate transformers.
ImportError: cannot import name 'TFBertModel' from 'transformers' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/__init__.py)

Comment: Is this because you install Pytorch and you need TF also? https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3442

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- Please update your GPU driver by downloading and installing a new
  version from the URL: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
- Alternatively, go to: https://pytorch.org to install a PyTorch
  version that has been compiled with your version of the CUDA driver.

Comment: Thanks! This is on the GCP AI Platform Notebook so I can't install a new version of the GPU driver. I am using the latest version of PyTorch.

Comment: @user3550693 Exatcly what i said: `install a pytorch version that has been compiled with your verion of the CUDA driver`

Comment: I added some more detail: The NVIDIA driver that it reports I have is actually one that is compatible with PyTorch.

Comment: @user3550693 The there are several versions of the pytorch package for different cuda versions. Have you installed `torch==1.6.0+cu101`?

Comment: I just tried torch==1.6.0+cu101 as you suggested, and it doesn't work (same error).

Comment: @user3550693 have you restarted your runtime to make sure that you are actually using 1.6.0+cu101?